Why I don't get copy trait error when I use a const for initilizing a string array?
When I try to initilize a string array with a const, everything is fine:
fn main() {
    const ARRAY_REPEAT_VALUE: String = String::new();
    let mut strings: [String; 5] = [ARRAY_REPEAT_VALUE; 5];
}

But when I replace const with an unmutable variable, I get an error:
fn main() {
    let array_repeat_value: String = String::new();
    let mut strings: [String; 5] = [array_repeat_value; 5];
}

The error is:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `String: Copy` is not satisfied                                                                 
 --> src/main.rs:3:37                                                                                                         
  |                                                                                                                           
3 |     let mut strings: [String; 5] = [array_repeat_value; 5];                                                               
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Copy` is not implemented for `String`                   
  |                                                                                                                           
  = note: the `Copy` trait is required because this value will be copied for each element of the array

I expected to get the copy trait error even when I use a const. How this behaviour is explained?

The documentation on arrays says:

There are two syntactic forms for creating an array:

A list with each element, i.e., [x, y, z].
A repeat expression [expr; N] where N is how many times to repeat expr in the array. expr must either be:

A value of a type implementing the Copy trait
A const value




So if the value you're creating the array from is const, it doesn't require Copy.
This makes sense because const values are instantiated upon each use; they can create as many owned values as you want without Copy. See the documentation on const for more details.

So can I use const to declare variables of types that doesn't implement copy trait and use their values without using clone method?
If so, is it even a good practice?

@MohammadHoseinMasoon Keep in mind that not everything can be const, so that is only an option for a narrow set of values that can be const-initialized (e.g. you can create a constant of String::new() but not of String::from("text")).
